# Can we have LaTeX formatting enabled?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tex

The title said it all. But, as a potentially mathematics heavy site, can we have LaTeX formatting enabled? On the meta site also?

Comment: It looks like LaTeX might already be enabled on the main site? See this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16/possible-closed-forms

Comment: Seems like it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has been enabled.  Enjoy. (:

Comment: Thanks, Rebecca.

Answer (score 2):

I had high hopes for mathML but

[image: Mathematica graphics]

comes out as

ⅇ

    x

   

   ⁢

   

    Cos

    [

    x

    ]

   

  

  -

  

   

    ⅇ

    x

   

   ⁢

   

    Sin

    [

    x

    ]

and

[image: Mathematica graphics]

as

∫

   

    -

    π

   

   ∞

  

  

   

    

     sin

     ⁡

     (

     x

     )

    

    

     x

     2

    

   

   ⁢

   

    ⅆ

    x

So it's either LaTeX or images.

Comment: using something like `TeXForm[TraditionalForm[#]] &` does a reasonable job of converting to TeX (at least for the cases I checked)