# How to pretty print keyboard buttons?

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

How do I enter keystrokes in a pretty printed form?

For example, the keyboard combination CTRL-SHIFT-D 
in [this answer](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/34) was pretty printed as

[image: keys]

Comment: Must read [<kbd> elements are way intrusive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1939/156389)  :P

Comment: A good reference for the implemented markdown and allowed inline html is [Markdown help](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: That's the second link in my post.

Comment: You're right! I guess you just didn't get to the [inline HTML section](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#html)...

Comment: Indeed, thanks : )

Comment: I rearranged your question a little in order to make it clean enough to be tagged [tag:faq] - just like the [corresponding question on meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19145/156389). I hope that is ok. (It makes a mess of the comments, but we can delete those[!](http://xkcd.com/378/))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The html tag to produce the <kbd>any</kbd> key is

```
<kbd>any</kbd>
```

---

Just to clarify:
Stackexchange sites use an [extended version of markdown](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and allows a [certain subset of standard html tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/156389). These tags work in questions, answers and tag wikis. Some stackexchange sites ([including the Mathematica one](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3/34)) also allow for LaTeX via [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) (you can thank the guys at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) for getting this working first).

The comments only allow a small subset of markdown and AFAIK none of the html tags. See the end of [this meta.SO answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79591/156389).

For examples of some more extreme uses of the allowed markdown, see the [meta.SO sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/156389)

Comment: I have to try it: <kbd>test</kbd>.

Comment: It seems that it does not work on my end.

Comment: It might only work in an answer field?

Comment: @IstvánZachar: as noted in the recent edit of this answer, only a limited subset of markup works in comments.

Comment: Thanks Isaac, I read it as well.